# c# Excel skipping first row?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I'm importing an xls file using OleDbCommand to a ds.  Problem I'm having is during the foreach on my ds its skipping for first row.  I can't figure out why.  Any suggestions?

```
cmd.CommandText = string.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}$]", worksheetName);
conn.Open();

var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
var ds = new DataSet();
adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
adapter.Fill(ds);
var table = ds.Tables[0];

foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows){ // rest of my code }
```

Comment: Has your spreadsheet got a header row?  If not I'd guess that it thinks you do and it's treating the top row as the column headers.

Comment: What's your connection string?  It most likely thinks the first row is a header and is ignoring it.

Comment: Maybe it takes the first line as the headline?

Comment: Can we see your "//rest of my code", as that may be were the problem is happening.

Comment: string cnn =
                    string.Format(
                        "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source={0}{1}{2};Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;",
                        fileLocation, fileName, fileExtension);

                var factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.OleDb");

Comment: Inside the foreach I just have  string test = row.ItemArray[0].ToString();

Comment: @DoctaJonez - No headers in excel spreadsheet.  Data starts column1, row1

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Change the connection string (as mentioned in comment) from:

```
string cnn = string.Format( 
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
    "data source={0}{1}{2};" +
    "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;", 
    fileLocation, fileName, fileExtension);
```

to:

```
string cnn = string.Format( 
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
    "data source={0}{1}{2};" +
    "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;HDR=No", 
    fileLocation, fileName, fileExtension);
```

Answer (score 7):

Check your connection string. Most likely it contains:

```
HDR=Yes
```

which indicates that first row is a header

Comment: ...and if it is, change it to `HDR=No`  :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've told it to skip first row. I remember a property that sounds something like FirstRowIsHeader. I think if that is set to true, then it skips. this can be changed at point you create your connection

Comment: Nope, the code is as pasted.  no instruction to skip first row! So unless it defaults to true.

Comment: Yes I think by defualt it is set to true, try setting HDR=No, use this http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel