# write excel data to datatable

Tags: c#, excel, datatable

I have written the code below to write data from an excel file to a datatable, but for some reason when writing to datatable the data for row at index 0 and 1 are not displayed. does anyone have an idea to why this could be..

```
var excelDataTable = new DataTable();
            var excelAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();

            var excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= " + excelFileName + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
            // Create Connection to Excel Workbook
            using (var excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString))
                {                    
                    excelConnection.Open();

                    var dt = excelConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                    if (dt != null)
                    {
                        var excelSheet =  new String[dt.Rows.Count];
                        int i = 0;
                        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                        {
                            excelSheet[i] = row["Table_Name"].ToString();
                            i++;
                        }

                        var command = new OleDbCommand
                            ("Select  * FROM [" + excelSheet[0] + "]", excelConnection); // should be first sheet not the name of the sheet, should be index

                        excelAdapter.SelectCommand = command;
                    }
                    excelAdapter.Fill(excelDataTable);
                    excelConnection.Close();
                }
```

Comment: I just tested with your code and it works fine (although I added `HDR=NO` into the connection string to get the first row). There must be something unusual about your spreadsheet or the way it's formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem in your connection string .................... If you want to avoid the header or want to include the header rows or start from first row you need to inlcude one more exnteded property of conncetion string for excel.

Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690604/c-sharp-excel-skipping-first-row)

[skip first row in read of Excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713048/skip-first-row-in-read-of-excel-file)

Answer (score 0):

About data from `row[0]` can help including the property `HDR=No;` in extended properties of your connection strong.

Comment: That because you are missing quotes. `Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=NO'` (Use single quot).

Comment: this still does not work.. it still does read the data in the rows but reads an extra data