# Read .XLS file without header row in datatable

Tags: c#, excel, datatable

I am reading a xls file and show it in gridview. I am using following code

```
string strSelectQuery = "Select * from [sheet1$]";    
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand= new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(strSelectQuery, mCon);
DataAdapter = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(strSelectQuery, mCon);
DataAdapter.Fill(mDTable);
```

Now what happens when i go for checking the follwing code

```
string strFirstCell =  mDTable.Rows[0][0];
```

It gives me result of second row first cell.
I wanna read the complete xls without any header row in datable.
I hope the first row is assigned as column name in datatable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add "HDR=No" in your connection string to stop taking first row as column header.
See this answer [c# Excel skipping first row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6690604/c-sharp-excel-skipping-first-row)